# Weird behaviour of division in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

2 servers (same gems, exactly same ruby version `2.2.2p95` installed)

**Development**

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.13)
[1] pry(main)> (1/3).class
=> Fixnum
[2] pry(main)> (1/3)      
=> 0
[3] pry(main)>
```

Production

```
Loading production environment (Rails 4.0.13)
2.2.2 :001 > (1/3).class
 => Rational 
2.2.2 :002 > (1/3)
 => (1/3) 
2.2.2 :003 >
```

wth ? The only difference between the two environments is that one uses rvm (production) the other not

Comment: I cannot reproduce `(1/3)` returning a `Rational` object. Perhaps you have some unusual monkey-patching either in a gem that's in the `:production` group of your `Gemfile`, or within some `if Rails.env.production?` conditional logic?!

Comment: Apparently I found out that `mathn` module is loaded in production and not development, how can I find out which gem requires it ?

Comment: @David `mathn` is in the standard library, so this won't be in the `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: no gems in the lock files requires it, but server has some gems installed manually (don't ask why..) so can I rely on something like `grep -rnw '.' -e "require 'math"` in the gempath ? cause this commands found out nothing

Comment: @kitensei Ahh, `mathn` of course! This library actually *re-defines* `Integer#/` as an alias for `Integer#quo`. I.e. `1.quo(3) == (1/3)`. Where exactly are you searching? You can try something like `bundle show rails` to see the folder for the bundled gems (which may be an rvm gemset?)

Comment: See: https://github.com/ruby/mathn/blob/master/lib/mathn.rb#L12-L18 and https://github.com/ruby/mathn/blob/master/lib/mathn.rb#L67-L76

Comment: Thanks for help, need to dig into different gems cause production server has gems not declared in gemfile (NewRelic for instance) which may cause the issue.. investigating who is requiring mathn now

Answer (score 1):

Ok the issue is due to a dependency gem using `mathn` module, trying now to figure out which gem is :)

Comment: For what it's worth, you're not the first person to be surprised by this unexpected global change caused by requiring `mathn`! The library has been [deprecated](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/12/25/ruby-2-2-0-released/) since ruby 2.2, and has now been [removed from the standard library](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10169) as of version 2.5 (which will be release next month).